# spring ABAC with Oauth token

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, abac

I am planning to leverage spring security to implement a mix of Oauth (Jwt) token  based with ABAC ( attributed based access control model). The ABAC is introduced in spring 5. I have looked at the implementation, but I am struggling to integrate seamlessly with Oauth token.

Appreciate for any advice?

Comment: See this article on ABAC and Spring Security: https://www.axiomatics.com/blog/spring-security-and-attribute-based-access-control/

Comment: @DavidBrossard thanks for suggestion but I need something much more detail and articulate on this topic.